# Tastypie documentation generation

Tags: django, python-sphinx, tastypie, documentation-generation

I'm trying to use auto-doc tool to generate API doc for Tastypie REST API. I tried Tastytool, but it seems not showing the API's result parameters but the model's columns. Then I tried Sphinx seems more promising since Tastypie supports Sphinx, but I can't find an example to show where & how to put comment for the API inside the code, and generate them into the document.

Anyone can share some info or example about correctly write comment and generate Sphinx doc for Tastypie based API? thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [tastypie-swagger](https://github.com/concentricsky/django-tastypie-swagger), which uses [Swagger](http://swagger.wordnik.com/) to generate a /doc/ page for your [Tastypie](http://tastypieapi.org) API.

I've had some success with it, after a few minor adaptations (which were necessary due to a tastypie version difference, I suppose).

**Edit:** The adaptations I found necessary (due to a django version < 1.4 and tastypie version > 0.9.11) are now merged into the mainline branch of tastypie-swagger.

Comment: tastypie-swagger doesn't support the latest django version. Any ideas on overcoming that hurdle ? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There's also [Django Tasty Docs](https://github.com/juanique/django-tastydocs) which is part of [Tasty Tools](https://tastytools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: That does not appear to be on the pip index for easy install :(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm completely missing the point of your question but if you are just trying to build the docs that come with the source distribution there is a Makefile in the docs directory that performs the necessary actions.  You are required to specify a target output type such as html, json, latex, etc. I keep a local copy of the docs for django, tastypie, and slumber as I use all three in conjunction with each other and I use the option `make html` frequently.

If I am mistaken about what you are trying to accomplish perhaps we can come to some clarification.

Comment: Sorry for not having clarified my question. I can generate the doc with Sphinx the build-in command line, but I can't find the correct place and format to put my comment for each API in my code and generate them into the doc.

Comment: So are you trying to write sphinx documentation for your own API classes that utilize Tastypie?